# Printing out a counter of a csv file

Tags: python, python-3.x, csv, counter

Please advise why is the expected output not achieved.

```
with open('data2.csv','r') as data:
  reader = csv.DictReader(data)
  for line in reader:
    x = Counter(line['Programminglanguages'].split(','))

print(x)
```

OUTPUT:

```
Counter({'C++': 1})
```

EXPECTED OUTPUT:

```
Counter({'Java': 2, 'C++': 2, 'Python': 1})
```

Contents of file data2:

[image]

Comment: Could you maybe provide a small snippet for testing?

Comment: Not sure how to do that. Can you guide?

Comment: For example, what are the contents of the line `line` where the output of `x` is `Counter({'C++': 1})`?

Comment: You create new `x` inside the loop - only the last one survives. - create `x` outside the loop - add to it inside the loop - do not recreate it all the time

Comment: If you include the contents for data2.csv, it will be possible to give some advice.

Comment: See [mre] for more information.

Comment: How can I show the content of the file data2?

Comment: Copy and paste it (or a portion of it) into your question and mark it up like it was code. We also need to now that the `Counter` class is — perhaps a `collections.Counter`?

Comment: No, not a screenshot image of the data, the actual data.

Comment: Yes, it is collections.Counter 
And I am trying but am unable to post the contents of file data2 here.

Answer (score 2):

You should use such code.

```
import csv
from collections import Counter


with open('data2.csv') as data:
    reader = csv.DictReader(data, delimiter=';')
    programming_languages = []
    for line in reader:
        programming_languages.extend(line['Programminglanguages'].split(','))
    print(Counter(programming_languages))
```